# change the value(text) of many buttons when i click a button from a button group

Tags: javascript

Hello i need some small help.
when i click one  of the first 5 buttons(these  buttons have no value(like input field)), a button group with 3 numbers 1 ,2 and 3 is displayed.
when i click on one of these buttons, the value(number) from the button i have clicked  override the value(text) from the button i have first clicked.
my problem: all the buttons have  been overrided from the value(text) of the number i have clicked.

```js
$(function() {

  var l = $("div.col-xs-12").length;

  function getRndInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }

  $("div#gr.btn-group").hide();

  $(".bt").click(function() {
    $("div#gr.btn-group").show();
  });


  $(".btt").click(function() {
    $('.bt').text($(this).text());
    $("div#gr.btn-group").hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.btn-group button {
  background-color: #103c52;
  border: 1px solid #1b1d1b;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}


/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */

.btn-group:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
  /* Prevent double borders */
}


/* Add a background color on hover */

.btn-group button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

button.bt,
button.btt {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button.bt {
  font-size: 25px;
  /* text-align: center; */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script> -->

<script src="https://www.google.com/cloudprint/client/cpgadget.js">
</script>
<!--   <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css"> -->
<!--google font api garamond-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Song+Myung" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="col-xs-12 " style="text-align: center;">
  <button class="bt"></button><br>
  <button class="bt"></button><br>
  <button class="bt"></button><br>
  <button class="bt"></button><br>
  <button class="bt"></button><br>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-12 " style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="btn-group" id="gr">
      <button class="btt">1</button>
      <button class="btt">2</button>
      <button class="btt">3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're assigning the text to all the buttons in this statement:

```
$('.bt').text($(this).text());
```

You may instead store a reference to the placeholder button (see the `clicked` variable in the following snippet) and then when a value button is clicked, assign the text to the saved reference only

```js
$(function() {
  var l = $("div.col-xs-12").length;
  var clicked = null;

  function getRndInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }

  $("div#gr.btn-group").hide();

  $(".bt").click(function() {
    clicked = $(this);
    $("div#gr.btn-group").show();
  });

  $(".btt").click(function() {
    clicked.text($(this).text());
    clicked = null;
    $("div#gr.btn-group").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-group button{background-color:#103c52;border:1px solid #1b1d1b;color:#fff;padding:10px 24px;cursor:pointer;float:left;border-radius:10px;margin-left:5px}.btn-group:after{content:"";clear:both;display:table}.btn-group button:not(:last-child){border-right:none}.btn-group button:hover{background-color:#3e8e41}button.bt,button.btt{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;line-height:inherit;width:60px;height:40px;border:2px solid #000;border-radius:5px}button.bt{font-size:25px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12 " style="text-align: center;">
  <button class="bt"></button><br>
  <button class="bt"></button><br>
  <button class="bt"></button><br>
  <button class="bt"></button><br>
  <button class="bt"></button><br>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-12 " style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="btn-group" id="gr">
      <button class="btt">1</button>
      <button class="btt">2</button>
      <button class="btt">3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: I've removed extra CSS/JS files from the snippet so that the snippet looks clear.